# How does one get an async React function calling firebase.firestore.set to wait whilst using an onSnapshot callback?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, snapshot

Here is [a simplified version] of my current code:

```
export const setTimestamp = async () => {
    console.log("START")
    let result = null;
    const dbRef = await firestore.collection("collectionName").doc("docName");
    const unsub = await dbRef.onSnapshot(snap => {
        result = snap.data();
        console.log("ACTUAL END", result);
    });
    await dbRef.set({ serverTime: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() });
    unsub();
    console.log("FUNCTION END", result);
    return result;
};
```

`FUNCTION END` is currently logged before `ACTUAL END` whilst I need it the other way around. Any ideas? Are there perhaps alternatives to using `onSnapshot`?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `onSnapshot` is an `event` that returns a `Promise` for the subscription. But the event will be fired after subscription. If you want to make sure the event is fired you need another `Promise` that handles the scenario:

```
const res = await new Promise( async resolve=> {
const unsub = await dbRef.onSnapshot(snap => {
        result = snap.data();
        
        console.log("ACTUAL END", result);
        resolve({result,unsub});
    });
});

await dbRef.set({ serverTime: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() });
res.unsub();
console.log("FUNCTION END", res.result);
return res.result;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Eldar's answer is correct but I subsequently found and prefer this approach:

```
import { v4 as UUID } from "uuid";

export const setTimestamp = async () => {
    let result = null;
    const dbRef = firestore.collection("collectionName").doc(UUID());
    await bdRef.set({ serverTime: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() })
        .catch(error => console.log("ERROR", error));
    await dbRef.get()
        .then(value => result = value.data())
        .catch(error => console.log("ERROR", error));
    return result;
};
```